# Is it wise to replace the trunk for shelvesets?

Tags: svn, tfs, trunk, shelveset

We're currently migrating from SVN to TFS;

Today there are Trunks, Branches and Tags to track and organize our development. But we are questioning the need of a trunk while we have shelvesets, and could just shelve the pending activities and unshelve & merge them as necessary into the main branch.

Is it a good plan ? Are there bad consequences upon doing this, has anyone tried before ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your rational for not having a trunk?

When you have changeset, there is no history on the 'trunk'. Although you can build from a shelveset, it is not possoble to build from multiple shelvesets (and thus validate a combined development effort).

It is also very risky and you could loose track very easy.

Altough it might be possible, I would never ever go for that route. You have branching in TFS Source Control, which works perfecly. Why trying to simulate this branching?

To see good guidance on branching, see [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/)